# How can I add items into a specific pre-existing column into a listview form?

Tags: vb.net

Every time I try to add an item it automatically goes under the first column.  How can I add it to the 2nd column?  I already made this userform with 4 columns in design mode.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'create a new ListView
    Dim ListView1 As ListView
    ListView1 = Me.ListView1
    ListView1.View = View.Details

    'Creating the list items
    Dim ListItem1 As ListViewItem
    ListItem1 = ListView1.Items.Add("Item 1")

    'How can I put this in the 2nd column
    Dim ListItem2 As ListViewItem
    ListItem2 = ListView1.Items.Add("Item 2")

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SubItems.Add` / `SubItems.AddRange` instead of `Items.Add`. `ListView` considers `Items` as the first columns. Also, you do not need to create `Dim ListView1 As ListView` if you already have `Me.ListView1`. It refers to the same `Control`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'create a new ListView
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details 'use Me.ListView1 directly will do

    'Creating the list items
    Dim otherItems As String() = {"Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add("Item 1").SubItems.AddRange(otherItems) 'use SubItems
End Sub
```

Result

[image]